# Linear differential equation on the complex plane solution has zero of order $n$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If $f(z)$ is a solution of $y^{(n)}(z) = a_{n-1}(z) y^{(n-1)}(z)+\cdots+a_{0}(z) y(z)$ having a zero of order $n$ then $f \equiv 0, \; \; \forall z \in R \in \mathbb{C}$ where $a_k \forall k \in \{0,1,2,..n-1\}$ are continous functions in the region $R$ which is open and connected in the complex plane.

I need help understanding the proof of this Lemma as stated by this : [Paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320224). After trying out with $n = 1$ I do not understand why this lemma would imply that the trivial solution only exists of a zero of infinite order.

Counter Example:
$n = 1$ Then Let us saying we have the following equation when $n = 1$ then we have

$y^1 = a_{0} y, \; a_{0} = g(z)$

Now this is easily solvable and the general solution is given by
$y = Ce^{\int a_{0} dz}, \forall C \in R$

Now note that the exponential function has no zeros $\iff$ no poles hence there does not
$\exists z_0,\; \text{such that } e^{z_0} = 0$.
Therefore
$ \not \exists z_0 \text{  s.t  } e^{\int a_{0} dz} = 0$

But the key lies in the fact that if we let $a_0 = 1/z$ then we get $y = z + C$ as a solution and clearly at $ z = -C$ we have $f(-C) = 0$ but $f'(-C) = 1$ which implies that the solution $f(z) $ has order $1$, but this is clearly not the trivial solution and hence why I cannot understand why this lemma works. I was thinking maybe it's because $1/z$ is not defined at 0 and hence not continuous in the region R ?

Regarding the general proof : From the hypothesis of our lemma and after substituting $f(x)$(which is a solution) in our original equation ie
$y^{(n)}(z) = a_{n-1}(z) y^{(n-1)}(z)+\cdots+a_{0}(z) y(z)$ it is clear that $f$ has a zero of order atleast $n+1$. $f(z_0) = 0, \; z_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now we prove this by contradiction. Suppose that $f$ is not identically $0$ ie
$f \not\equiv 0$ then $\exists p \geq 1$ such that $f$ has a zero of order $n+p$ at $z_0$.

Why is this true? Why does would a solution have a zero of order at least $n + 1$ when it already has a zero of order $n$ doesn't that contradict the definition of a zero of order $n$? Then how do we go about assuming it has order $n+p$? If anyone would be so kind as to explain the general proof and how this lemma is proved I would be grateful as I have tried a lot but still cannot understand why this works.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: it is not true that for $a_0=1/z$ we have $z+C$ a solution in general as $1 \ne \frac{z+C}{z}$  unless $C=0$ so $f(z)=z$ and then of course $0$ is not in the domain of $a_0$ - as $a_0$ is required to be continuous for the lemma to hold - hence the lemma is still true ($f$ has no zeroes on a domain where the equation makes sense so in the punctured plane)

Comment: @Conrad Oh yes, that makes sense Thank you! Do you mind then explaining why the author says " the solution has a zero of order n+1", I do not see why they hypothesize that ?

Comment: Zero of order $n$ means all derivatives are zero up to order $n-1$ (starts at the function which is the zeroth derivative) and then the differential equation gives that the nth derivative is zero too so the zero is automatically order $n+1$ when it is order $n$ by hypothesis